# Illegal combination of modifiers: public and private

Tags: java, syntax-error, class-visibility

I am having an issue with the following code...

```
/**
 * This class holds all of the information pertaining to 
 * a person's name.
 */
public class Name {

    private String first, middle, last, maiden, initials, prefix, suffix;
    private char middleInitial, firstInitial, lastInitial;
    private

    /**
     * Constructor for a Name given first, middle, and last names.
    */
    public Name(String first, String middle, String last) {

        this.first = first;
        this.middle = middle;
        this.last = last;
        this.middleInitial = middle.charAt(0);
        this.firstInitial = first.charAt(0);
        this.lastInitial = last.charAt(0);
        this.initials = String.valueOf(firstInitial + middleInitial 
            + lastInitial);
        this.maiden = null;
        this.prefix = null;
        this.suffix = null;

    }
```

There is more but my error is coming in my primary constructor. It is giving me the error that I have entered in the title. As you can see, both my class and constructor are both public. This shouldn't cause any issues but seems to be doing so.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have an "orphan" `private` modifier before the constructor's comment:

```
private // Here!

/**
 * Constructor for a Name given first, middle, and last names.
 */
public Name(String first, String middle, String last) {
```

Just remove it, and you should be fine.

Comment: wow, thanks. Looking at code too long today already. Little things are starting to get me. thanks

Comment: That is why it is better to list each class member on separate line.

Comment: @MaxZoom Even though I agree that listing on seperate line looks better, I don't see how listing on a seperate line avoids that issue

Answer (score 6):

There is a stray `private` on the third line inside the class. Since statements last until a curly brace or semicolon is encountered, the compiler thinks that this is a part of the same statement as your constructor declaration - it sees `private public Name(String first, String middle, String last)`.

Comment: wow, thanks. Looking at code too long today already. Little things are starting to get me. thanks

Answer (score 2):

After declaring all your variables, you have written the keyword `private`.

```
private String first, middle, last, maiden, initials, prefix, suffix;
private char middleInitial, firstInitial, lastInitial;
private  // Here.
```

Java is a freely-typed language. A line ends with a `;`(semi colon) and not a newline. So

```
private  

public Name(String first, String middle, String last) {
    // ...
}
```

is considered to be one single line as:

```
private public Name(String first, String middle, String last) {  
  // ...
}
```

As you can see, your constructor has two modifiers, `public` and `private`. Which is illegal in Java.

## Solution

1. Remove the keyword `public` if you want to keep the constructor `private` and **DO NOT** want other classes to instantiate it.

## OR

2. Remove the keyword `private` if you want to allow other classes to instantiate it.